# Bayes formula for Gaussian Process in terms of functions

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process

Reading Chapter 2.1 of Rasmussen the book states, in pg. 9, that in the weight space view the Bayes formulation for a GP is

$$\text{P($\mathbf{w}$|$\mathbf{y}$, X)} = \frac{\text{P($\mathbf{y}$|X, $\mathbf{w}$)}\text{P($\mathbf{w}$)}}{\text{P($\mathbf{y}$|X)}}$$

Great, now if the *parameters* are $\mathbf{f}$ in function space. Then is it safe to rewrite Bayes as,

$$\text{P($\mathbf{f}$|$\mathbf{y}$, X)} = \frac{\text{P($\mathbf{y}$|X, $\mathbf{f}$)}\text{P($\mathbf{f}$|X)}}{\text{P($\mathbf{y}$|X)}}$$

Now although this is not mentioned in the book (possibly because its a no brainer?) I would just like to make sure that I could write this formula this way. My worries is that there might be some underlying theory, that im not aware of, regarding the change from weight space to function space such that the use of notation, too, differs.

Comment: You changed two things, replaced $\mathbf{w}$ with $\mathbf{f}$ and used the conditional $\mathbf{f|X}$. Are you asking about the first thing or both? Notice that in the second case $\mathbf{X}$ needs to be a random variable if you want to condition on it.

Comment: @Tim , The first, from $w$ to $f$, initially. But now that you mentioned the conditional $f|X$ I obtained this from pg 19, chapter 2.3 in Rasmussen, specifically Eq. (2.29) Where they define the log of the prior as $log(p(\mathbf{f}|X))$ = .... Thus i figured that $p(\mathbf{f}|X)$ is indeed how you write the prior